# WCF access configuration with multiple endpoints (IIS)

Tags: wcf, rest, iis

I'm working on a WCF project and right now I have four ServiceContract,

- three (e.g. A, B, C) of them are accessable via http, endpoints with: mexHttpBinding / webHttpBinding
- the fourht (e.g. D) is accessable via https, endpoints: mexHttpsBinding / webHttpBinding with Transport security mode
  and every of them are REST based. The service will be run on IIS 8.

I want to achieve the following:

- restrict acces from "outside" to A, B and C (communicate only on localhost with a webproject on the same server)
- make D public becaues it receives data from an external source

I read a lot of articles and posts about this (e.g. IPFilter, namedpipes, stackoverflow answers, etc.) but sadly I haven't found the perfect solution yet. 
I think, the best would be to do this on "server-level", so with IIS configuration, but I don't know how can I use different rules for
different contracts/endpoints.

What would be the best solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd a similar scenario, and I used IPFilter to do the work.
As you just want to restrict the access by external address, it can be good solution, it's simple and easy to implement.

Comment: I read a post on codeproject about WCF IPFiltering, but that one only supports ipv4 and I need ipv6 support too.